# SEVERE: Context initialization failed

Tags: spring

```
ERROR [2015-06-23 10:12:50,826] localhost-startStop-1 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanExpressionResolver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:249)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 17 more
```

This is my applicationcontext.xml file...

ApplicationContext.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform"><ref bean="dialect"/></property>
        </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/iclassifieddb"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dialect" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" autowire-candidate="false">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/dialect"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <!-- Startup bean -->
    <bean id="databaseSetup" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.util.DatabaseSetup">
        <property name="mutableAclService" ref="aclService"/>
        <property name="configurationDao"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- DAOs -->
    <bean id="categoryDAO"
            class="com.Yasna.iclassified.category.CategoryDAOJPA">
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationItemDAO"
            class="com.Yasna.iclassified.configuration.ConfigurationItemDAOJPA">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataElementDAO"
            class="com.Yasna.iclassified.dataelement.DataElementDAOJPA">
    </bean>

    <bean id="postingDAO"
            class="com.Yasna.iclassified.posting.PostingDAOJPA">
        <property name="propertyHelperFactory"><ref bean="propertyHelperFactory"/></property>
        <property name="luceneIndexer"><ref bean="luceneIndexer"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyDAO"
            class="com.Yasna.iclassified.property.PropertyDAOJPA">
    </bean>

    <bean id="imagePropertyDAO"
            class="com.Yasna.iclassified.property.ImagePropertyDAOJPA">
        <property name="configurationDAO"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDAO"
            class="com.Yasna.iclassified.user.UserDAOJPA">
    </bean>

    <!-- Controllers. Remember to specify the appropriate DAO as the dao parameter  -->
    <bean id="categoryController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.category.CategoryController">
        <property name="dao"><ref bean="categoryDAO"/></property>
        <property name="postingDAO"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
        <property name="securityHelper"><ref bean="securityHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.configuration.ConfigurationController">
        <property name="dao"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataelementController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.dataelement.DataElementController">
        <property name="dao"><ref bean="dataElementDAO"/></property>
        <property name="categoryDAO"><ref bean="categoryDAO"/></property>
        <property name="securityHelper"><ref bean="securityHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="postingController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.posting.PostingController">
        <property name="dao"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
        <property name="categoryDAO"><ref bean="categoryDAO"/></property>
        <property name="propertyDAO"><ref bean="propertyDAO"/></property>
        <property name="dataElementDAO"><ref bean="dataElementDAO"/></property>
        <property name="configurationDAO"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
        <property name="mutableAclService"><ref bean="aclService"/></property>
        <property name="propertyHelperFactory"><ref bean="propertyHelperFactory"/></property>
        <property name="securityHelper"><ref bean="securityHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="postingListController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.posting.PostingListController">
        <property name="postingDAO"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
        <property name="categoryDAO"><ref bean="categoryDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.user.UserController">
        <property name="dao"><ref bean="userDAO"/></property>
        <property name="securityHelper"><ref bean="securityHelper"/></property>
        <property name="userHelper"><ref bean="userHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Property Helpers -->
    <bean id="propertyHelperFactory" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.property.PropertyHelperFactory">
        <property name="helperMap">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                       <value>SHORT_TEXT</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="textHelper"/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                       <value>LONG_TEXT</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="textHelper"/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                       <value>IMAGE</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="imageHelper"/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                       <value>CURRENCY</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="currencyHelper"/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                       <value>DEFAULT_CURRENCY</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="defaultCurrencyHelper"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>                
    </bean>

    <bean id="textHelper" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.property.TextPropertyHelper">
        <property name="propertyDAO"><ref bean="propertyDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="imageHelper" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.property.ImagePropertyHelper">
        <property name="propertyDAO"><ref bean="imagePropertyDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="currencyHelper" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.property.CurrencyPropertyHelper">
        <property name="propertyDAO"><ref bean="propertyDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultCurrencyHelper" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.property.DefaultCurrencyPropertyHelper">
        <property name="propertyDAO"><ref bean="propertyDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Miscellaneous actions -->
    <bean id="homeController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.util.HomeController">
        <property name="configurationDAO"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
        <property name="userDAO"><ref bean="userDAO"/></property>
        <property name="securityHelper"><ref bean="securityHelper"/></property>
        <property name="userHelper"><ref bean="userHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="profileController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.user.ProfileController">
        <property name="userDAO"><ref bean="userDAO"/></property>
        <property name="postingDAO"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
        <property name="securityHelper"><ref bean="securityHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="getFile" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.util.GetFileAction">
        <property name="propertyDAO"><ref bean="imagePropertyDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="postingSearchController" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.posting.PostingSearchController">
        <property name="postingDAO"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
        <property name="luceneSearcher"><ref bean="luceneSearcher"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationCacheAction" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.configuration.ConfigurationCacheAction">
        <property name="configurationItemDAO"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Interceptors -->
    <bean id="propertiesInterceptor" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.struts.PropertiesInterceptor">
        <property name="userDAO"><ref bean="userDAO"/></property>
        <property name="postingDAO"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Scheduled Jobs -->
    <bean id="expiryJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="postingDAO" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="expirePostings" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="expiryTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="expiryJob" />
        <!-- run every hour -->
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 * * * ?" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="versionCheck" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.util.VersionChecker">
        <property name="configurationDAO" ref="configurationItemDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="versionCheckJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="versionCheck" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="checkVersion" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="versionTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="versionCheckJob" />
        <!-- run every day at midday -->
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 12 * * ?" /> 
    </bean>

    <!--
    <bean id="extraTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="expiryJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 * * * * ?" /> 
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- A list of Triggers to be scheduled and executed by Quartz -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="expiryTrigger"/>
                <ref bean="versionTrigger"/>
                <!-- <ref bean="extraTrigger"/> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Email configuration -->
    <bean id="mailProperties" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.util.MailProperties">
        <property name="configurationDAO"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" scope="prototype" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host">
            <bean factory-bean="mailProperties" factory-method="getHost"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <bean factory-bean="mailProperties" factory-method="getPassword"/>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <bean factory-bean="mailProperties" factory-method="getUser"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emailController" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.email.EmailController">
        <property name="postingDAO"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
        <property name="emailHelper"><ref bean="emailHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emailHelper" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.email.EmailHelper">
        <property name="mailSender"><ref bean="mailSender"/></property>
        <property name="securityHelper"><ref bean="securityHelper"/></property>
        <property name="configurationItemDAO"><ref bean="configurationItemDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Lucene Indexing -->
    <bean id="fsDirectory" class="org.springmodules.lucene.index.support.FSDirectoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="lucene"/>
        <property name="create">
            <value>true</value> 
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="indexFactory" class="org.springmodules.lucene.index.support.SimpleIndexFactoryBean">
        <property name="directory" ref="fsDirectory"/>
        <property name="create">
            <value>true</value> 
        </property>
        <property name="analyzer">
            <bean class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="luceneIndexer" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.lucene.LuceneIndexer">
        <property name="indexFactory"><ref bean="indexFactory"/></property>
        <property name="propertyHelperFactory"><ref bean="propertyHelperFactory"/></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="searcherFactory"
          class="org.springmodules.lucene.search.factory.SimpleSearcherFactory">
        <property name="directory" ref="fsDirectory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="luceneSearcher" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.lucene.LuceneSearcher">
        <property name="searcherFactory"><ref bean="searcherFactory"/></property>
        <property name="analyzer"><bean class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer" /></property>
        <property name="postingDAO"><ref bean="postingDAO"/></property>
        <property name="dataElementDAO"><ref bean="dataElementDAO"/></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Miscellaneous Beans -->
    <bean id="securityHelper" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.security.SecurityHelper" />
    <bean id="userHelper" scope="prototype" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.user.UserHelper">
        <property name="emailHelper"><ref bean="emailHelper"/></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is security for the above context file.

securityApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">
    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/category/Category/create*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/configuration**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <form-login login-page="/common/login.jsp" />
    </http>

    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDAO'>
        <password-encoder hash="sha">
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled"  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>

    <!-- ACL permission masks used by this application -->
    <beans:bean id="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.READ"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="staticField" value="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.READ"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.WRITE"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="staticField" value="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.WRITE"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.CREATE"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="staticField" value="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.CREATE"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.DELETE"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="staticField" value="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.DELETE"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="staticField" value="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- An access decision voter that reads ROLE_* configuration settings -->
    <beans:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.vote.RoleVoter"/>

    <!-- An access decision voter that reads ACL_POSTING_WRITE configuration settings -->
    <beans:bean id="aclPostingWriteVoter" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.security.GenericsAclEntryVoter">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg value="ACL_POSTING_WRITE"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.WRITE"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:property name="processDomainObjectClass" value="com.Yasna.iclassified.posting.Posting"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- An access decision voter that reads ACL_POSTING_DELETE configuration settings -->
    <beans:bean id="aclPostingDeleteVoter" class="com.Yasna.iclassified.security.GenericsAclEntryVoter">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg value="ACL_POSTING_DELETE"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.DELETE"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:property name="processDomainObjectClass" value="com.Yasna.iclassified.posting.Posting"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- An access decision voter that determines if there is an existing authentication -->
    <beans:bean id="authenticatedVoter" class="org.springframework.security.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>

    <!-- An access decision voter that reads JSR 250 annotations -->
    <beans:bean id="jsr250Voter" class="org.springframework.security.annotation.Jsr250Voter"/>

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="roleVoter"/>
                <beans:ref bean="jsr250Voter"/>
                <beans:ref bean="authenticatedVoter"/>
                <beans:ref bean="aclPostingWriteVoter"/>
                <beans:ref bean="aclPostingDeleteVoter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

  <!-- ========= ACCESS CONTROL LIST LOOKUP MANAGER DEFINITIONS ========= -->

    <beans:bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
                <beans:property name="cacheManager">
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"/>
                </beans:property>
                <beans:property name="cacheName" value="aclCache"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="lookupStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                            <beans:constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                        </beans:bean>
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                            <beans:constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                        </beans:bean>
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                            <beans:constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                        </beans:bean>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger"/>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="aclService" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

This is the web.xml contains the filter mappings...
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="iClassified" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>iClassified</display-name>

    <!-- Include this if you are using Hibernate -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-  class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>
            iClassified data source.
        </description>
        <res-ref-name>
            jdbc/iclassifieddb
        </res-ref-name>
        <res-type>
            javax.sql.DataSource
        </res-type>
        <res-auth>
            Container
        </res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/*Context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

This is what i have as code and the above is what i got as error..
Please help and Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you check org.springframework dependencies is correct?

Comment: Kindly share what is issue . Provide some more details

Comment: Sorry bro i'm a fresher.I dont know the actual error. This is what i get when i run the project.

Comment: May be i can upload the xml files.

Comment: You dont have all the required dependencies on the classpath when you run your project

Comment: Thanks @Nadir,
But it would be better if you explain it a little bit more...

Comment: Solved it..,
Thanks for the responses guys...,
Especially @Nadir.. :)